# How to access multiple sub folders with ServeStaticModule in Nestjs?

Tags: typescript, nestjs, subdirectory

I have two different modules for images of **Posts** and **Profile**.So I can save the images in two different sub folders of assets.

**My folder structure**

[image]

Now the issue is I can access the `posts` folder images on google like this `http://localhost:3000/47b7a6b9c10.jpg`

but when I try to access the **profile** folder images
like this `http://localhost:3000/93d1a567c5.png` I got blank page. And can't see the image.

**The Current Code In app.module.ts**

```
 PostsModule,
    ProfileModule,

    ServeStaticModule.forRoot(
      {
        rootPath: join(__dirname, '..', 'assets/posts'),
      },
      {
        rootPath: join(__dirname, '..', 'assets/profile'),
      },
    ),
```

**Things that I tried with**

**1-**

```
ServeStaticModule.forRoot({
      rootPath: join(__dirname, '..', 'assets/posts'),
    }),

ServeStaticModule.forRoot({
      rootPath: join(__dirname, '..', 'assets/profile'),
    }),
```

**2-**

```
    ServeStaticModule.forRoot(
      {
        serveRoot: '/assets',
        rootPath: join(__dirname, '..', '/posts'),
      },
      {
        serveRoot: '/assets',
        rootPath: join(__dirname, '..', '/profile'),
      },
    ),
```

**3-**

```
    ServeStaticModule.forRoot({
      serveRoot: '/assets',
      rootPath: join(__dirname, '..', '/posts'),
    }),

    ServeStaticModule.forRoot({
      serveRoot: '/assets',
      rootPath: join(__dirname, '..', '/profile'),
    }),
```

**With My Current Code I can access the sub folder that is present at first. Like If I replace `assets/posts` with `assets/profile` I can access profile images and vice versa**

Answer (score 3):

I've found the solution for my particular situation. The term `renderPath` did the trick.

**Sloution**

```
ServeStaticModule.forRoot(
      {
        rootPath: join(__dirname, '..', 'assets/posts'),
        renderPath: '/posts',
      },
      {
        rootPath: join(__dirname, '..', 'assets/profile'),
        renderPath: '/profile',
      },
    ),
```

**To get further information about other `ServeStaticModule API SPEC options` and `properties` visit https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nestjs/serve-static**